# Cannot see Netflix titles, however can browse folder structure

Tags: raspbmc, streaming-video

I'm really curious as to how people manage to setup the PlayOn server->RaspBMC connection. I bought PlayOn, entered my Netflix credentials, have installed the MPG2 key on RaspBMC, and have added the "folder" in Videos.
But all I can do is browse the folder structure of Netflix (which suggests I must have done something right). When I get down to where actual titles would have been, it is empty.
Lots of people present how to solve the Netflix problem via PlayOn, but nobody seems to have this precise problem.